# How do I get my items back in VS 2015

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I installed VS 2015 on windows 10. Then I installed Xamarin. I got some errors then when I start up VS. So I uninstalled Xamarin. Now when I go to create a new project no items appear in the new project dialog. How do I fix this[image]

Comment: repair Visual Studio via control panel->programs & features, select VS2015 with updates and click on modify and next repair

Comment: Thank you. I will attempt this now

Comment: Nope. This didn't work

Comment: Turns out the Devexpress controls I installed was causing the problem

Comment: ok, post this as answer with the used version. Maybe others also run into this issue

Comment: However. I installed the same windows/other software/visual studio/devexpress on another machine in the same order with the same settings on all software and no problems. Strange but true